# Pest found on sunflowers

Tags: pests, pest-control

I found some black/white dots that are on my sunflower leaves and flower. I can't tell if they are pests or infected with disease.

Could someone help ?

[image: Leaf with several small black & brown bugs]

[image: Another similarly affected leaf]

Comment: Probably whitefly larvae, but the pictures are not clear enough for me to be sure.